# redirect https to http with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

Next month ssl certificate expires, so Irevert from https to http.

I used

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainame.it/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And works great for root..

```
https://www.domainame.it/ becomes http://www.domainame.it/
```

but all post URL instead doesn't work.

```
https://www.domainame.it/post-id.html remains https://www.domainame.it/post-id.html
```

I tried all solutions. This is the only one that at least works for root.

Comment: Have you updated your Wordpress Address and Site Address options?

Answer (score 0):

just to try it, check to set {HTTPS} =**off**
and set the Port to "80" instead of "433"

First try to set only the Port.
If it does not work then try onöy to change **HTTPS off**.
If both dont worked, try to setup both**"off & 80"**

Generally i think it should work if u setup both.

You have 3 possibilities.
Please try them first.

**Regards mate ;)**